# automate the boring stuff comma code

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.x, function

```
spam = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']

def stringmaker(data):
    tempdata = 0
    datastring = ''
    stringlist = []
    stringdata = ''
    stringdata += ', '.join(data)
    stringlist += stringdata.split()
    tempdata = stringlist
    tempdata = str(stringlist.insert(-1, 'and'))
    datastring += ' '.join(stringlist)
    print(datastring)


stringmaker(spam)
```

in Automate the Boring Stuff with Python page 102, practice project Comma Code - Comma Code

> Say you have a list value like this: spam = ['apples', 'bananas',
>   'tofu', 'cats'] Write a function that takes a list value as an
>   argument and returns a string with all the items separated by a comma
>   and a space, with and inserted before the last item. For example,
>   passing the previous spam list to the function would return 'apples,
>   bananas, tofu, and cats' . But your func- tion should be able to work
>   with any list value passed to it.

The code I wrote works and stays within the context of the chapter. I've looked at other answers on this site and on google and I'm amazed at how different and probably stupid my code code is. Can someone help me point out all the bad things about my code?

I'd really like this to be as pythonic and as few lines as possible.

Comment: If this is **working code** that you think could be improved, see [codereview.se]. But note that *"as pythonic and as few lines"* can sometimes conflict.

Comment: `data[0] if len(data) == 1 else ', and '.join([', '.join(data[:-1]), data[-1]])` is how I would do it

Answer (score 2):

It'll do your work:

```
spam = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats',]
def commacode(spam):
    return print(', '.join(spam[:-1]) + ' and ' + spam[-1])

commacode(spam)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def stringmaker(data):
    return ", ".join(data[:-1]) + " and " + data[-1]
```

What it does :  join the list BUT THE LAST ELEMENT with ", ", then add " and " and the last element

As the comment in your question said, it is sometimes better so abandon 'one-liners' in order to make your code more readable.

Also please note that for now this code doesn't work if data is an empty list

Comment: I'd remove your first example, considering the second one is both shorter and more readable. Also, your functions don't have `return` statements.

Comment: What is `table`? Did you mean `data`?

Comment: I followed both of your advices

Comment: @WNG `... + ", and " + ...` if you want to follow the spec - it includes the oxford comma.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

```
words = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']
def spam(words):
   if words: # prevents parsing an empty list
        return ", ".join(words[:-1]) + ", and " + words[-1]
print spam(words)
# apples, bananas, tofu, and cats
```

---

[Demo](http://ideone.com/ydCwH5)

---

Note:
In English, you normally don't use `commas` before `and`.

Comment: I would disagree that "you don't normally use" a [serial comma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma)

Comment: There's some controversy about this, for example, Associated Press doesn't use comma before coordinating conjunctions. Anyway...thank you for pointing that! My mother language is Portuguese and we don't use ***virgulas*** (commas) before ***e*** (and) ;)

Answer (score 0):

I did this exercise but thinking on the user input as a  list: (lista == list but in spanish :3 )

```
 import sys
lista = []

while True:
    print('enter the '+ str(len(lista) + 1) +' item in your list ' "(or enter nothing to stop)")
    item = input()
    if item == '':
        break
    lista = lista + [item]
lista[-1] = 'and ' + lista[-1]
print('your complete list is: \n' + (", ".join(lista)))
sys.exit()
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Can you please explain a bit more in detail what you are trying to achieve and add some tags about the technologies/languages that are used?

Comment: well i tried to make this programs as flexible as i could, by making custom lists every time, i used python 3.x.
Im new on this >.< hope i didn't broke any "Code of Conduct"

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution,Like you i struggled three days partially to solve this problem.
But it was really awesome.

Here is THE CODE:

```
spam = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']
def list_string(the_list):
 number_list = len(the_list)
 if number_list == 1:
     print(the_list[0])
 elif number_list == 2:
     print(the_list[0] + ' and ' + the_list[1])
 elif number_list > 2:
     for a in range(1):
         print(', '.join(the_list[0 :len(the_list) - 1]) + ', and ' + the_list[len(the_list) - 1])



list_string(spam)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got

```
list = []
for i in range(3):
    value = str(input())
    list.append(value)
list.insert(2, 'and')
print(list)
```

That way the only thing that needs to change depending on how long you want the list would be the range(3) and the .insert(2, 'and') part of the code.

Answer (score -1):

I think this gives the best output.(p.s: i am also a beginner).

```
def ltos(list):
    empty_string = ''
    for i in list[:-2]:
        empty_string += i + ", "
    empty_string += list[-2]
    empty_string += ' and ' + list[-1] + '.'
    print(empty_string)

myex = ['dumb', 'retard', 'awkward', 'brainless', 'immature', 'ignored', 'invisible']
ltos(myex)
```

output: dumb, retard, awkward, brainless, immature, ignored and invisible.